# How can I identify the time offset between two similar, but materially different, MP3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3

I have hundreds of pairs of instrumental/vocal MP3 files. The instrumental version has music played with instruments. The vocal version does too, but it also has a vocal track overlaid.

I don't know what all processing went into creating these MP3 files, but I do know that the instrumental and vocal versions often do not have the same length, and they often start with a different length of silence.

I need to figure out what the offset is between each pair of MP3 files. Because there are so many of them, I would prefer a command line or batch solution.

I don't know anything about signal processing, I'm hoping for some existing tool that can easily do this. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. What operating system (OS) are you using? 2. How are the files arranged and named--i.e. all in one folder, with same starting names? 3. How do you now know which instrumental file goes to the corresponding vocal file?

Comment: 1. Mac OS X. 2. Currently as two folders with identical names in each, but I can trivially change that to whatever is needed. 3. They have the same name.

Comment: So, in one folder, you have for example song-abc.mp3 and in another folder song-abc.mp3 and therefore you already know which are the instrumental and which are the vocals and instrumentals, because all vocals are in one folder and all instrumentals are in another? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: Well, one way would be to be able to export the properties of the file to a csv / Excel file and then you can have a column calculating the difference. So, the columns could be something like folderpath1, song, time/duration, folderpath2, song, time/duration, difference in time. I however don't know how to get this information. I was looking around yesterday at file managers, but though one of them exports information like name and dates, it doesn't export other fields like duration. I would suggest looking at such programs and see if they can help you. See next comment for more info.

Comment: [File Managers][File Managers]http://alternativeto.net/software/multicommander/?platform=mac and [more file managers]http://alternativeto.net/software/freecommander/?platform=mac . These usually have dual panes and compare features. The other better alternative though would be for you to go to a programming forum and to ask for help there. I don't think extracting the information would be too difficult for a good to expert programmer. They might even write the code for you. You can try Stack Overflow, but I don't think you will get a good response if you are asking for it to be written.

Comment: Getting the duration is easy. Figuring out the offset to align the two MP3s is unfortunately not.

Comment: If you are able to get the difference in time between a pair of mp3s, and you are sure that number would represent the silence duration, and you are sure the silence is at the beginning, then all you need is a program to read the list of times (i.e. 2 seconds, 3 seconds, etc.) from a file, and to delete that amount from the instrumental or vocal versions, whichever set has the silence at the beginning. Another approach, if you only care about removing the silence and not whether each pair equals the same duration in the end, would be to look for software that removes silence from mp3s.

Comment: I don't know how much silence is at the start and how much is at the end. I also can't change the files. I also don't know if silence is the only difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074512/1709223) recommends [SOX](http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/) which looks like it deserves looking into.

Comment: Brilliant. I was making this way too complicated.

Comment: I combined the post you pointed me to with [a post on parsing sox output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534372/get-length-of-wav-from-sox-output). I can now get the length of the starting silence of any given MP3, which I can use to calculate offsets between paired MP3s. Thank you!